# Sesame 2.7 crashes during Java program

Tags: java, crash, rdf, sesame

In my Java program I'm creating a local Sesame storage, as shown below:

```
File repoDir = new File("./RDF_repository/");
if (!repoDir.exists())
    repoDir.mkdir();
repository = new SailRepository( new NativeStore(repoDir) );
repository.initialize();
```

And I add new RDF files doing this:

```
RepositoryConnection con = repository.getConnection();
try {
    // As I may add some DBpedia files, I set these non fatal errors.
    Set<RioSetting<?>> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add( BasicParserSettings.VERIFY_DATATYPE_VALUES );
    set.add( BasicParserSettings.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_DATATYPES );
    con.getParserConfig().setNonFatalErrors(set);//*/

    con.add(uri.toURL(), null, RDFFormat.RDFXML);
}finally {
    con.close();
}
```

The strange thing is, after some time of execution, the program crashes and a "hs_err_pid" log file is generated by the JVM. The head of the file is:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9215385e40, pid=6172, tid=140265570998016
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  org.openrdf.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.QueryJoinOptimizer$JoinVisitor.meet(Lorg/openrdf/query/algebra/Join;)V
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try     "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
#
```

(I'm not sure if the rest of the file is important to analyse the problem. If it is, let me know.)

It has been happening several times and, every time, according to this information, the problem appear to be the "`org.openrdf.query.algebra.evaluation.impl.QueryJoinOptimizer`" class. Or, maybe, the way I'm creating and adding the new RDF files.

The version of Sesame I'm using is 2.7.3. And Java version 1.7.

Someone has any idea of what is happening? =/

Thanks!

EDIT:

Also, I'm doing queries. The code follow below:

```
con = repository.getConnection();

TupleQuery tupleQuery = con.prepareTupleQuery( QueryLanguage.SPARQL, query);
TupleQueryResult result = tupleQuery.evaluate();

try {

    while (qResult.hasNext()) {
        BindingSet set = qResult.next();

        Value prop = set.getValue("prop");

        if (prop != null) 
            result.add(prop.stringValue());
    }

} finally {
    qResult.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Above, the `query` variable contain a SPARQL query. All the query codes follows the code above. My program do a lot of queries, they are not complex and, also, not concurrent.

Comment: I've never seen that happen before. At first glance it looks like a problem in your particular version of Java rather than something fishy in Sesame itself. Does it also happen if you try running with a different JRE (Oracle, or OpenJDK 6)?

Comment: Also rather astonished that you can get an error in the `QueryJoinOptimizer` while uploading data...

Comment: I tested my system in three different machines, two with Java 1.7.0_07 (Windows and Ubuntu) and the another with Java 1.7.0_25 (Fedora). I also made the same test through a Sesame server with Tomcat6. This last test crashes tomcat. At first I was trying to find errors in my code, but everything seems to be right. And just now, I was seeing this link - https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-1872 - saying that a bug was fixed in QueryJoinOptimizer... =/

Comment: that bug could not possibly be the cause of a Java SIGSEGV.

Comment: What, exactly, is your program doing when the error occurs? Your code looks like you're only uploading, but as said, the SIGSEGV error indicates the query optimizer is involved - which can not be the case unless you're also querying.

Comment: Yes. My code is doing queries. I will edit my post and add them.

Comment: These queries are simple queries asking for the type, superclasses and properties of a RDF instance. They have nothing of special. My program just do a lot of them. I also note that, when I'm working with DBpedia resources, the crash is more easy to happen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33432/discussion-between-jeen-broekstra-and-rick)